# Removing a table with a specific class using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, removeclass

Hey guys I am trying remove a table id but only a specific class.

```
<table id="toc" class="toc plainlinks"
```

I am so close but I do not know how to incorporate a class id into my jquery script. I do not want to remove the entire id because sometimes I need that id. But I never need that specific class (toc plainlinks)

here is what i have

```
$('table#toc').remove();
```

That removes the table id="toc" but i need to get that class in there somehow...

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to remove the attribute class from the element, or the element itself?

Comment: It's not clear what you need, do you have multiple tables with the same id? with the same class? which do you want to remove? just a general tip make sure you're not repeating ids in your markup **Id attributes should be unique in a HTML page**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy:

```
$('table.toc').remove();
```

or even (if you want your selector to be more precise):

```
$('table.toc.plainlinks').remove();
```

But may be you wanted to remove the class itself, then you should do:

```
$('table.toc').removeClass('toc');
```

You should do some research before asking though as this is jQuery basics.

Answer (score 1):

use the class name selector:

```
$('table.classname').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#toc").removeAttr("class");
```

In this way you just removing the class and everything else is still there.